# Plot not generating until program exits

Tags: python, while-loop

I have created a data analysis application which gives the user a number of options to explore. Each option ends with a visualisation. I have included a while loop to allow the user repetitive querying but the plots do not generate in the order that I'd like the program to proceed. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style

style.use("ggplot")


def main():
    series1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
    series2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))

    df = pd.concat([series1, series2], axis = 1)
    df.columns = ["X", "Y"]
    back2menu = "y"

    while back2menu == "y":
        choice = input("Choose option 1 or 2:\n1.) Y against X\n2.) X against Y")
        if choice == 1:
            plt.scatter(df.X, df.Y)
            plt.show()
            back2menu = raw_input("Return to main menu? (y/n)")
       elif choice == 2:
            plt.scatter(df.Y, df.X)
            plt.show()
            back2menu = raw_input("Return to main menu? (y/n)")
       else:
            print("Application closing.")
```

Everything runs fine but the plot doesn't generate before asking the user whether they would like to return to the main menu or not. Only when the program exits does the plot show up. Ideally, I'd like the plot to pop up then the return to menu prompt. How can I manage this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is plt here? Which library are you using?

Comment: @adarshdec23 matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: I actually think this is a problem with Spyder on my machine. It works fine on Windows OS but not on my version (Linux).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're testing 'choice' as the wrong type. input from 'input()' is parsed as a str. I modified the choice cases to test against a str and this resolved the issue.

e.g.

```
if choice == '1':
--code--
elif choice == '2':
--more code--
...
```